# Inheritance (through files) unable to find class?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

Im trying to use Inheritance through multiple header and cpp files for a text game that I'm writing.

I have my base class of Weapon. Which is in the file Weapon.h

```
class Weapon
{
    public:
        string Name;
        int Damage;
        float ChanceToHit;
        int ExtraDamage;
        int Result;
        int Array[3];
        int Attack(int, int, string);
};
```

I am then trying to inherit form the base Weapon.h class to a Bow and Sword class. I am sure I am including the file correctly but when I try to compile I get the error *"error: expected class name class Blade : public Weapon"* The same error for the Bow class.

```
#include "Weapon.h"
#include "Crossbow.h"

using namespace std;

class Bow : public Weapon
{
    public:
        string Type = "Ranged";
        bool loaded;
    protected:
        Bow();
}; 

#include "Weapon.h"
class Blade : public Weapon
{
    private:
        string Type = "Melee";
    protected:


  void Draw();
};
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? Google isn't coming up for anything useful either. Thanks

MCVE (I think)

```
//In Base.h
class Base
{
 public:
    int function();
 private:
};

//In Base.cpp
int Base::function()
{
    randomshit
    return 0;
}

//In Inherit.h
#include "Base.h"
class Inherit : public Base
{
public:
    int function():
private:
};

Getting error: "expected class name class Bow : public Weapon"
```

EDIT: Turns out I needed to include "#pragma once" and that solved almost everything. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: At which line do you get the error ? What is in `crossbow.h` ?

Comment: Probably a circular include dependency. But why do you `#include "CrossBow.h"`?

Comment: @MichaelWalz I get the error in the "class Bow" line, same for Blade class. For the Crossbow, I then Inherit the Bow class. I just included that #include there because I couldn't think of anything else that would solve my problem.  I also get the issue in the Crossbow.h file. For some reason I don't get the issue when I inherit within the same file.

Comment: @juanchopanza I couldnt think of anything else to do, so I started to randomly include other files hoping it would fix it and I havn't removed them yet. Also for some reason I don't get the issue when I inherit from within the same file.

Comment: could you just add the error?

Comment: @Pandrei `/Users/Matt/Documents/C++ programming docs/C++ Assignment/Bow.h:20:20: error: 
      expected class name
class Bow : public Weapon
`

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: all the files are in the same directory ..right?

Comment: Working on my side. How do you compile this?

Comment: @MichaelWalz I added what I think is a MCVE

Comment: @Pandrei Yes I even tried to include to entire directory to the file.

Comment: @JulienLopez I've tried compiling using Xcode, as well as c++ in the terminal. Obviously on OS though.

Comment: @Matt what you added is not an MCVE. `int function():` you have a `:` instead of a `;` right after the closing `)`. Click ont [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and read what an MCVE is.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use any include guards, so your file Weapon.h is probably included multiple times, leading to the compilation error.

To know more about include guards: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Include_Guard_Macro

Your header Weapon.h would then become:

```
#ifndef WEAPON_H_INCLUDED
#define WEAPON_H_INCLUDED

class Weapon
{
public:
    string Name;
    int Damage;
    float ChanceToHit;
    int ExtraDamage;
    int Result;
    int Array[3];
    int Attack(int, int, string);
};

#endif // WEAPON_H_INCLUDED
```

Do the same for all other header files.

Once you did that, remove all unnecessary includes and do a clean rebuild.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged - add more detail

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe not an answer but it just is impossible to post it as comment

This compiles (but does not link !!) on my Visual Studio 2013.

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Weapon
{
    public:
        string Name;
        int Damage;
        float ChanceToHit;
        int ExtraDamage;
        int Result;
        int Array[3];
        int Attack(int, int, string);
};    

class Bow : public Weapon
{
    public:
        string Type = "Ranged";
        bool loaded;
    protected:
        Bow();
};     

class Blade : public Weapon
{
    private:
        string Type = "Melee";
    protected:    
        void Draw();
};
```

But it is likely to fail on older compilers because of the initialisation in the declaration as `string Type = "Melee";`.

Note that `using namespace std;` comes *before* the declaration of `class Weapon`.

Comment: Thanks I'm probably going to just start fully over and see if the problems persist.